# Georeferencing Control Points Aren't Saving

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, georeferencing

I have some CAD data that needs to be georeferenced. I create my first control point, and everything goes well, the drawing shifts to the correct control point.  As soon as I try to create a second control point, the first control point disappears.  Then it acts as if my *second* control point is now the *first* control point.

I've done this before, but I'm not sure what the problem is now.

Process:

- I bring in my .dwg file.
- Open the georeferencing toolbar, select the file I want to georeference, then I click the "Add Control Points" button.
- I click where I want my first control point, then right click and select "Input DMS of lon and lat." (I prefer to create control point using this method).
- Once I enter the lat and long, that creates my first control point.
- I repeat this process to create my other control points, however instead of creating a second and third control point, it "starts over" at control point #1 and will NOT create a second and/or third point.

Comment: The world file must be named esri_cad.wld http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/about-georeferencing-cad-datasets.htm

Comment: @Mapperz But I've done this many times using the .dwg and I haven't had any problems.  I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: Have you set the coordinate system of the dataframe before you start georeferencing? Are there other layers in the table of contents?
According to this question you can only have 2 control points anyway. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/is-it-possible-to-use-more-than-two-control-point-links-when-georeferencing-cad?rq=1